# Using enums correctly

Tags: enums

Wondering why I can't use the following code.

```
enum  player_state { fast, slow, focus, bust, out};




if (score >= 100)
        player_state = fast;
    else if (score > 50)
        player_state = slow;
    else if ((score <= 50) && (score > 1))
        player_state = focus;
    else if ((score == 1) || (score < 0))
        player_state = bust;
    else
        player_state = out;
```

I get an error at the assignment's (=).

any tips? I thought I could do something like this, if not exactly this.

Comment: Try to include the compilation error in the post. You need to declare a variable of enum player_state and then assign values to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An enum is a type declaration. You have to make a variable that uses that type.
For instance

```
enum  player_states { fast, slow, focus, bust, out};
player_states playerState = fast;
```

Comment: Where would I do this? Still getting the same error?

Fixed it, thank-you. :D

Comment: My code was only there as an example, not as the exact formatting you should use. What you'd have to do is to add a variable declaration before your conditional block and adapt the assignments and checks to use that variable instead of on the type itself